# How to develop firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a firefox add-on using SDK, and use `jpm run` to test it.

But everytime I changed someting in my code, I have to close my browser and than use `jpm run` to start browser and test it.

Can I update it without restart firefox?

I have made some search on google, some people told me that I should use `Extension Auto-Installer` add-on.(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/)

As its description says, this extension will listen a port at localhost(by default, at 8888)

After I installed it, I use the command `wget --post-file=tieba.xpi http://localhost:8888/` to post my add-on, and here is what wget returned

[image]

and nothing happend in my firefox.

Is there any mistake in my operation?

Or is there any way to debug my add-on without restart firefox?

Comment: Why do you think anything would happen in firefox if it removed and immediately replaced the extension?

Comment: The good thing with `jpm run` is that it creates a clean temporary test profile (and this requires of course to restart Firefox)...

Comment: @the8472 Well, I changed some text in my code, and then post it to the browser. But nothing changed, so I think it doesn't work.

Comment: @Aurélien Is there any way to test my add-on without restart my browser?

Comment: The old (XUL) way was to put the code folder directly in the extensions folder of the profile (and you could set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false`). However, with the new SDK structure, this folder seems to be wiped out by Firefox. So **don't do this**, especially if you don't have a copy of your code.